# How to get response form Oracle using C#?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I'm new in Oracle and trying to execute the next SQL request using C#

```
try
{
    connection.Open();
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.CommandText = "select count(*) from agreements";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dr.Read();
}
```

I've read Oracle documentation, I've tried to use

`var response = dr.GetString(0);`

But it always returns exception

> Specified cast is not valid.

Does somebody know how I can solve it ? Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Well you're fetching `count(*)`. Why would you expect the result to be a string?

Comment: about dr.GetString(0); probably the first one is not an String... as @JonSkeet already said, check what are you fetching to match it to a type

Comment: @JonSkeet oh, thank you for good unswer, I've used GetValue(); and solved it. I thought what oracle returns string :/

Comment: @UladzimirKhadakouski: Well did you actually read my answer suggesting that you shouldn't be calling `ExecuteReader()` in the first place? Don't go for "the simplest thing that fixes the immediate issue" - take a bit of time to do the right thing.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes I did, but not all, you've deleted unswer, can you share link where I can read more about it ? Please.

Comment: @UladzimirKhadakouski: Um, no, I haven't deleted my answer - you've accepted it! As for where to read more about `ExecuteScalar()` - look at the documentation for `OracleCommand`...

Comment: @JonSkeet I know, oh, you've edited your unswer, or was one more unswer as your, I've reloaded page and miss it. Ok, thank you again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that you're querying `count(*)`, you'd be better using `ExecuteScalar` rather than `ExecuteReader()`, for one thing. Next, the result will be an integer, which is why `GetString()` fails.

Change it to:

```
int count = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

(I'd also strongly advise using `using` statements for your connection, command, and any readers you'd normally create.)